# Update SQL Server CE rows with dynamic data

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, sql-server-ce

I am working on a solution where I track changes from a grid and to show all changes in a form to check the changes. so I have several DataRows where I know that the user did some modifications. and now I want to update the rows in my SQL Server CE database. But how? How can I update a single row in SQL Server CE?

The poblem is, that I cannot use objects because the data is dynamic. that means that I never know the structure of an "object" in my case. therefor I have to build a variable command for the insert. I think the simplest way would be to update only the changes of a row, but where can I get only the changes of a DataRow? the following information would be helpful:

- columns where the changes made
- values of each column and change

with this information I should be able to create a SQL command to update a single row, isn't it?

I also use the bulk insert from here http://sqlcebulkcopy.codeplex.com/

maybe I am wrong?!? any suggestions?

thanks,
tro

Comment: You can bind the data to a DataSet, and using DataGridView, you can automatically update the underlying table, wothout writing any SQL statments, see my SQL Server Compact Toolbox for sample code (on Codeplex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind the data to a DataSet, and using DataGridView, you can automatically update the underlying table, wothout writing any SQL statments, see my SQL Server Compact Toolbox for sample code (on Codeplex)